# How to calculate and list Writen down value against depreciated amount in double declining bal depreciation with Vue2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I am creating a fixed asset depreciation calculator with VueJS. The issue is calculating double declining balance and listing results in a table showing year, depreciated amount in each year a long the useful years of the asset and the book value in each year. I want something like this:
Purchase price = 25000
useful years = 5
**

```
Year| Depreciated Amount| Book Value
1   | 9000              |16000
2   | 6000              |10000
```

**

Asset purchase price and useful years is dynamically supplied by the user. Like in my example above, the loop should run 5 times (5 useful years).

This my code:

```
reducingBalDepCal()
      {
      //Calculates asset depreciation based on declining balance
      //hide previous results if any
      this.showResults = false;
      //This is the historical cost of the fixed asset. The value is being supplied by the user.
        var purchasePrice = this.reducingbal.purchase_price;
        //The number of years the asset will be useful to the business. Its the lifespan of the asset in the operational business. The vulue is being supplied by the user.
        var usefulYears = this.reducingbal.useful_years;
        //is calculated by dividing 100% with asset useful years.
        var rate = (100/usefulYears);
        //Then the rate is doubled

      var doubleDepreciationRate = rate*2;
      var depAmount = [];  //This array holds depraciated amount each year. i.e current book value-current depreciated amount

      var writenDownValue = []; //This array holds the current book value in each depreciation iteration

      //The for loop calaculates the depreciation in each year depending on the number of useful years and stores current depreciated amount in the depAmount array and the current writen down amount (book value) in the writenDownValue array.
      for(var i=usefulYears+1;i>1;i-=1)
      {
       writenDownValue.push(purchasePrice-=(doubleDepreciationRate/100)*purchasePrice);
       depAmount.push(purchasePrice-writenDownValue[i]);


      }
               //Assigns the results on data variable
               //this.reducingBalProjection =depAmount;
               this.showReducingBalProjection = true;
               console.log(writenDownValue);
               console.log(depAmount);



      },
```

This is the result for depAmount array:

```
(50) [15000, 9000, 5400, 3240, 1944, 1166.4, 699.84, 419.904, 251.9424, 151.16544, 90.699264, 54.4195584, 32.65173504, 19.591041024, 11.754624614399999, 7.052774768639999, 4.231664861183999, 2.5389989167103995, 1.5233993500262397, 0.9140396100157437, 0.5484237660094462, 0.3290542596056677, 0.1974325557634006, 0.11845953345804036, 0.07107572007482421, 0.04264543204489453, 0.025587259226936717, 0.01535235553616203, 0.009211413321697217, 0.00552684799301833, 0.003316108795810998, 0.0019896652774865986, 0.0011937991664919593, 0.0007162794998951756, 0.00042976769993710535, 0.0002578606199622632, 0.00015471637197735793, 0.00009282982318641476, 0.00005569789391184885, 0.00003341873634710931, 0.000020051241808265585, 0.00001203074508495935, 0.0000072184470509756104, 0.000004331068230585366, 0.0000025986409383512197, 0.0000015591845630107317, 9.35510737806439e-7, 5.613064426838634e-7, 3.36783865610318e-7, 2.020703193661908e-7]
```

And result for writenDown array:

```
[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, -0.017058172817957813, -0.05572336453866218, -0.10924812013634315, -0.19190570777038227, -0.3257381508098567, -0.5464341007319596, -0.9128458108492518, -1.5226830705263446, -2.5385691490104625, -4.231407000564037, -7.052620052268022, -11.754531784576812, -19.590985326106086, -32.65170162126365, -54.41953834875819, -90.69925196925492, -151.16543278155294, -251.94239566893177, -419.90399740135905, -699.8399984408155, -1166.3999990644893, -1943.9999994386935, -3239.999999663216, -5399.999999797929 ]
```

Both results are semantically wrong. I expect the loop to run usefulyears fold. But both loops are not doing what I expected and probably doing what I told it do. I cant figure out how exactly can achieve the intended results.

Another worry how can I package the do arrays and print them out in a table like this:

```
Year| Depreciated Amount| Book Value
1   | 9000              |16000
2   | 6000              |10000
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting two arrays of length `50`, isn't the main issue that `this.reducingbal.useful_years` is incorrectly set?

Anyway, implementing the calculation as described [here](https://www.thebalance.com/double-declining-balance-depreciation-method-357573) gives me different results than your first two years of `9000` and `6000`:

[image: double declining balance depreciation]

```js
(function() {
  // A table row
  const Row = (nr, start, apdr) => ({
    year: nr,
    startValue: start,
    depExpense: start * apdr,
    endValue: start - (start * apdr)
  })

  // The calculation
  const decliningBalanceDepreciation = multiplier => (
    startValue,
    endValue,
    years
  ) => {
    const valueDecrease = startValue - endValue;
    // Applicable Percentage Depreciation Rate
    const apdr = (valueDecrease / years) / valueDecrease * multiplier;

    const rows = [
      Row(1, startValue, apdr)
    ];

    for (let i = 1; i < years; i += 1) {
      rows.push(
        Row(i + 1, last(rows).endValue, apdr)
      )
    }
    
    return rows;
  };
  
  const dblDecBalDep = decliningBalanceDepreciation(2);
  
  console.log(
    dblDecBalDep(25000, 0, 5)
  );


  function last(arr) { return arr[arr.length - 1]; }
}())
```